# Azure function deployment using terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I have the below terraform code to deploy the function app and function to the Azure portal using zip deployment.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.50.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "mssql_to_blob_service_plan" {
  name                = "mssql_to_blob_service_plan-service-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mssql_to_snowflake_etl.name
  location            = var.default_location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}

locals {
  tmp_azure_function_zip = "../tmp/code.zip"
  azure_function_local_basedir = "../snowflake_sync_function"
}

data "archive_file" "snowpipefunctionzip" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = local.tmp_azure_function_zip
  excludes    = ["__pycache__"]

  source {
    content  = file("${local.azure_function_local_basedir}/__init__.py")
    filename = "__init__.py"
  }

  source {
    content  = file("${local.azure_function_local_basedir}/function.json")
    filename = "function.json"
  }

  source {
    content  = file("${local.azure_function_local_basedir}/requirements.txt")
    filename = "requirements.txt"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "mssql_to_snowflake_app" {
  name                        = "mssql-to-snowflake-app-new"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.mssql_to_snowflake_etl.name
  location                    = var.default_location
  storage_account_name        = azurerm_storage_account.staging_storage_account.name
  storage_account_access_key  = azurerm_storage_account.staging_storage_account.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id             = azurerm_service_plan.mssql_to_blob_service_plan.id

 
  zip_deploy_file             = data.archive_file.snowpipefunctionzip.output_path # local.tmp_azure_function_zip
  site_config {}
  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" = "0"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "mssql_to_snowflake_app_func" {
  name            = "mssql-to-snowflake-function"
  function_app_id = azurerm_linux_function_app.mssql_to_snowflake_app.id
  language        = "Python"
  test_data = jsonencode({
    "name" = "Azure"
  })

  config_json = jsonencode({
    "bindings" = [
      {
        "authLevel" = "function"
        "direction" = "in"
        "methods" = [
          "get",
          "post",
        ]
        "name" = "req"
        "type" = "timerTrigger"
      },
      {
        "direction" = "out"
        "name"      = "$return"
        "type"      = "http"
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

I am using the latest terraform provider for Azurerm, I get this error:

> Error: creating Function App Function: (Function Name "mssql-to-snowflake-function" / Site Name "mssql-to-snowflake-app-new" / Resource Group "mssql_to_snowflake_etl_rg") - State: "Running" / InProgressOperationID: 
> with azurerm_function_app_function.mssql_to_snowflake_app_func
> on azure_fun.tf line 63, in resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "mssql_to_snowflake_app_func":
> resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "mssql_to_snowflake_app_func" {
> creating Function App Function: (Function Name "mssql-to-snowflake-function" / Site Name "mssql-to-snowflake-app-new" / Resource Group "mssql_to_snowflake_etl_rg") - State: "Running" / InProgressOperationID:

Could someone please help in sorting the details of the below error or help with any documentation or example which explains deploying the Azure function using terraform zip deployment using the latest terraform Azure provider?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using the zip_deploy_file attribute. According to the documentation Using this value requires either WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 or SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true to be set on the App in app_settings.

Your function app is configured to WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0.

Azure functions can either have code deployed as a zip package or have code deployed inline for each function. The error you receive is actually on the function app function which would make sense if the code package isn’t loaded then your reference to the function wouldn’t work because the package isn’t loaded.

Can you share your code package? Or at least a sample one?

Comment: I have 3 files in the zip package __init__.py , function.json , requirements.txt file .

Comment: I am trying to deploy a sample timer trigger based azure function using Terraform . I am not able find any examples or documentation explaining the same

Comment: Same zip file works when i try deploying from local using the below command az functionapp deployment source config-zip --name <azure-function-app-name> --resource-group <azure-resource-group-name> --src <path-to-zip-file>

Comment: @mahesh did you manage to solve your problem? I also deploy an Azure Function with a .json included but the function binding is not correctly attached (it's deployed but the trigger is not working).

Comment: @TimbusCalin -try to test the triggers from the azure portal using code+test. you should be able to capture the exact error from logs.

Comment: I did that, the deployment goes well, but the triggering just doesn't work. Could you check this thread, maybe you have an answer. @Azure Terraformer _ mahesh maybe you can both have a look here to answer my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090332/azure-python-function-code-deployment-triggering-does-not-work