# Converting azure data factory source code to terraform script

Tags: terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I have the below azure sourcedataset and sinkdataset source code, I am trying to write a terraform script to create the datasets. I am able to create a basic dataset, but if I try to achieve the same with parameters, I am getting errors to run the terraform script.

I am using azurerm version = "3.50.0"

**SinkDataset**

```
{
    "name": "SinkAllParquetDataset_withTableName",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "TableName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "FileName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "SchemaName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "Parquet",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "fileName": {
                    "value": "@concat(dataset().FileName,formatDatetime(utcnow(),'_ddMMyyyy_hhmmss'),'.parquet')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "folderPath": {
                    "value": "@concat(dataset().SchemaName,'/',dataset().FileName,'/',formatDatetime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'/',formatDatetime(utcnow(),'MM'),'/',formatDatetime(utcnow(),'dd'),'/')\n",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "container": "latest-parquet-container"
            },
            "compressionCodec": "snappy"
        },
        "schema": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

**SourceDatset**

```
{
    "name": "All_Tables_SourceDataset",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabaseLinkedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "schema": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

**Terrafrom Script**

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_dataset_sql_server_table" "source" {
  name       = "All_Tables_SourceDataset"
  folder = "datasets"
  
  definition = jsonencode({
    name = "All_Tables_SourceDataset"
    properties = {
      linkedServiceName = {
        referenceName = "AzureSqlDatabaseLinkedService"
        type = "LinkedServiceReference"
      }
      annotations = []
      type = "AzureSqlTable"
      schema = []
    }
    type = "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
  })
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_dataset_azure_blob" "sink" {
  name       = "SinkAllParquetDataset_withTableName"
  folder = "datasets"
  definition = jsonencode({
    name = "SinkAllParquetDataset_withTableName"
    properties = {
      linkedServiceName = {
        referenceName = "AzureStorageLinkedService"
        type = "LinkedServiceReference"
      }
      parameters = {
        TableName = {
          type = "string"
        }
        FileName = {
          type = "string"
        }
        SchemaName = {
          type = "string"
        }
      }
      annotations = []
      type = "Parquet"
      typeProperties = {
        location = {
          type = "AzureBlobStorageLocation"
          fileName = {
            value = "@concat(dataset().FileName,formatDatetime(utcnow(),'_ddMMyyyy_hhmmss'),'.parquet')"
            type = "Expression"
          }
          folderPath = {
            value = "@concat(dataset().SchemaName,'/',dataset().FileName,'/',formatDatetime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'/',formatDatetime(utcnow(),'MM'),'/',formatDatetime(utcnow(),'dd'),'/')"
            type = "Expression"
          }
          container = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
        }
        compressionCodec = "snappy"
      }
      schema = []
    }
    type = "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
  })
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following:

***In this case create source and sink linked services to get the connection strings to refer in ARM template.***

*ex: "${azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database.example.connection_string}*"
,
"*${azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database.example.name}*"

source here in this case is blob and sink is sql database

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "stdg" {
  name                     = "storageaccountfdg"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}


resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "karepexample"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}


resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_blob_storage" "example" {
  name              = "neexamplels"
  data_factory_id   = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.stdg.primary_connection_string
}
```

[data_factory_linked_service_azure_blob_storage | terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_linked_service_azure_blob_storage)

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_dataset_azure_blob" "example" {
  name                = "exampledsb"
  data_factory_id     = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  linked_service_name = azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_blob_storage.example.name

  path     = "foo"
  filename = "bar.png"
}
resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database" "example" {
  name              = "example"
  data_factory_id   = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  connection_string = "data source=serverhostname;initial catalog=master;user id=testUser;Password=test;integrated security=False;encrypt=True;connection timeout=30"
}
```

See [data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database | terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database)

Then these have to be refered in the below code:
Below code can be checked where Arm template can be deployed using terraform script .

It also includes parameters.

**Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "example" {
  name                = "kaadfdeployment"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"
    
  template_content =  <<TEMPLATE
{ 

    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "dataFactoryName": {
            "type": "String",
              "defaultValue": "newdfforrepo",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the data factory. Must be globally unique."
            }
        },
        "dataFactoryLocation": {
            "defaultValue": "East US",
            "allowedValues": [
                "East US",
                "East US 2",
                "West Europe",
                "Southeast Asia"
            ],
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location of the data factory."
            }
        },
        "AzureStorage_connectionString": {
            "type": "SecureString",
              "defaultValue": "${azurerm_storage_account.stdg.primary_connection_string}",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Connection string for the Azure Storage account."
            }
        },
        "blobContainer": {
            "type": "String",
              "defaultValue": "newbbcontr",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the blob container in the Azure Storage account."
            }
        },
        "inputBlobFolder": {
            "type": "String",
              "defaultValue": "newbbfldr",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The folder in the blob container that has the input file."
            }
        },
        "inputBlobName": {
            "type": "String",
              "defaultValue": "newinpblbr",
              
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the input file/blob."
            }
        },
        "AzureSqlDatabase_connectionString": {
            "type": "String",
              "defaultValue": "<give sql db connection string here>",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Connnection string for the Azure SQL database."
            }
        },
        "sqlTableName": {
            "type": "String",
              "defaultValue": "mynewinptble",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the target table in the Azure SQL database."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "azureStorageLinkedServiceName": "azstrls",
        "azureSqlDatabaseLinkedServiceName": "AzSqlDbLinkedService",
        "inputDatasetName": "rInputBlobDataset",
        "outputDatasetName": "rOutputSqlDataset",
        "pipelineName": "rCopyFromBlobToSqlPipeline"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
            "apiVersion": "2017-09-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('dataFactoryLocation')]",
            "properties": {},
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "linkedservices",
                    "apiVersion": "2017-09-01-preview",
                    "name": "[variables('azureStorageLinkedServiceName')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "AzureStorage",
                        "description": "Azure Storage linked service",
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "connectionString": {
                                "value": "[parameters('AzureStorage_connectionString')]",
                                "type": "SecureString"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "linkedservices",
                    "apiVersion": "2017-09-01-preview",
                    "name": "[variables('azureSqlDatabaseLinkedServiceName')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                        "description": "Azure SQL Database linked service",
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "connectionString": {
                                "value": "[parameters('AzureSqlDatabase_connectionString')]",
                                "type": "SecureString"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "datasets",
                    "apiVersion": "2017-09-01-preview",
                    "name": "[variables('inputDatasetName')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
                        "[variables('azureStorageLinkedServiceName')]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "AzureBlob",
                        "structure": [
                            {
                                "name": "Prop_0",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Prop_1",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "format": {
                                "type": "TextFormat",
                                "columnDelimiter": ",",
                                "nullValue": "\\N",
                                "treatEmptyAsNull": false,
                                "firstRowAsHeader": false
                            },
                            "folderPath": "[concat(parameters('blobContainer'), '/', parameters('inputBlobFolder'), '/')]",
                            "fileName": "[parameters('inputBlobName')]"
                        },
                        "linkedServiceName": {
                            "referenceName": "[variables('azureStorageLinkedServiceName')]",
                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "datasets",
                    "apiVersion": "2017-09-01-preview",
                    "name": "[variables('outputDatasetName')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
                        "[variables('azureSqlDatabaseLinkedServiceName')]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
                        "structure": [
                            {
                                "name": "FirstName",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "LastName",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "tableName": "[parameters('sqlTableName')]"
                        },
                        "linkedServiceName": {
                            "referenceName": "[variables('azureSqlDatabaseLinkedServiceName')]",
                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "pipelines",
                    "apiVersion": "2017-09-01-preview",
                    "name": "[variables('pipelineName')]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[parameters('dataFactoryName')]",
                        "[variables('inputDatasetName')]",
                        "[variables('outputDatasetName')]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "activities": [
                            {
                                "type": "Copy",
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "source": {
                                        "type": "BlobSource",
                                        "recursive": true
                                    },
                                    "sink": {
                                        "type": "SqlSink",
                                        "writeBatchSize": 10000
                                    }
                                },
                                "name": "MyCopyActivity",
                                "inputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "[variables('inputDatasetName')]",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "outputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "[variables('outputDatasetName')]",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
 
TEMPLATE

}
```

[image]

[image]

Source

[image]

Sink

[image]
**Reference :** [Create an Azure Data Factory using ARM template | Microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-resource-manager-template)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer , do you have sample working code for deploying azure function . I have put the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75908106/azure-function-deployment-using-terraform