# Azure (Python) Function Code Deployment --- Zip Deployments' trigger does not work

Tags: python, azure, terraform, azure-functions, devops

I have an Azure Linux Function App that I am deploying using TerraForm.

I have Linux Function + Consumption Plan.

The .zip function contains `3 .py scripts, one __init__.py and function.json`.

The code deployment goes well, but the triggering does not work (the function is an Azure Storage Blob Trigger that fires when a specific file is uploaded on the blob container).

If I use the Azure Function Core Tools, the deployment goes well and the triggering works (I open the log streams/monitor and I see the function is constantly polling for objects inside that container).

If I use the CLI or TerraForm to upload the code, the triggering does not work.

Here is my code for the `function_app`:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "blurring_fn_app" {
  name                        = "blurring-app-new4"
  location                    = var.location
  resource_group_name         = var.resource_group
  storage_account_name        = var.storage_account
  storage_account_access_key  = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sensestgaccountkey.value
  service_plan_id             = azurerm_service_plan.blurring_app_service_plan.id
  functions_extension_version = "~4"
  app_settings = {
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.appinsightskey.value}"
    "AzureWebJobsStorage"            = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.azure_web_jobs_storage.value}" 
    "ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD"              = true
    "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT" = true
  }
  site_config {
    application_insights_key               = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.appinsightskey.value
    application_insights_connection_string = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.appinsightsconnstr.value
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.9"
    }
  }
}
```

What I already tried:

1. I tried using the func CLI deployment, which works for the uploading, **but the function is not triggered**.
2. I tried using the     `"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"= azurerm_storage_blob.storage_blob_function.url` (.zip of scripts uploaded to an Azure Storage Blob, this must be an URL in case of Linux apps + Consumption Plan), which works as well for the uploading, **but the function is not triggered.**
3. I also tried using `zip_deploy_file = path_to_local_zip` as a parameter inside the `azurerm_linux_function_app` and it still did not work.
4. For all 3 options above, I tried to manually sync the triggers : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/sync-function-triggers?tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0 but that did not work either.

The `function.json` is the following:

```
   {
      "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
      "bindings": [
        {
          "name": "myblob",
          "type": "blobTrigger",
          "direction": "in",
          "path": "blobcontainername/{name}.mp4",
          "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
        }
      ]
    }
```

How can I make sure the function is triggered?

Comment: Continuous deployment is not yet supported for Linux apps running on a Consumption plan.

Comment: Can you show me the source? Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? @Bingo

Comment: @Bingo I solved the problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `host.json` and `requirements.txt` were not at an upper-level folder.

Essentially, it was the `.zip` archive which was not done properly, not the TerraForm code.

The .zip structure should have the following hierarchy:

```
 <project_root>/
 | - .venv/
 | - .vscode/
 | - my_first_function/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | | - example.py
 | - my_second_function/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - shared_code/
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - my_first_helper_function.py
 | | - my_second_helper_function.py
 | - tests/
 | | - test_my_second_function.py
 | - .funcignore
 | - host.json
 | - local.settings.json
 | - requirements.txt
 | - Dockerfile
```

In my case, I just forgot to add - `host.json`.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use the CLI or TerraForm to upload the code, the triggering does not work. I tried using the func CLI deployment, which works for the uploading, but the function is not triggered.

Yes, it does work for me when i deploy it using Azure CLI using below commands:

```
$u="C:\Users\Downloads\BlobTrigger.zip"
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "name of resource grp" -n "function app name"  --src $u
```

[image]

Deployed:

[image]

After successfull deployment, I uploaded a file as below:

[image]

Then to test, I checked the logs as below:

[image]

I am providing an alternative way to do it, it may work for you or this answer may help for community. I have given in cli as you mentioned in question about not working with cli too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, as I mentioned in the question, it's not a problem of how I write the az cli deployment code, it's that the trigger is not synchronized. I suspect it is a problem with the azurerm_linux_function_app, some settings that I do not correctly set. I successfully upload the code both with the CLI and the TerraForm command but the triggering is not synchronized (the polling on the blob is not working).

Comment: If you have any other ideas on what configuration should be done on the TerraForm code do inform me. Thank you.

Comment: @TimbusCalin can you try the solution mentioned to troubleshoot?

Comment: @HassanSohail no, because I have already tried what you mentioned there, as you can see from the text of the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many restrictions on the consumption plan, perhaps you can try switching to a different plan.

[image: Continuous deployment is not yet supported for Linux apps running on a Consumption plan]
[Continuous deployment for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment)

Comment: So this means that neither from DevOps nor from TerraForm can the code be successfully deployed on a Linux App + Consumption plan?